# If-else in @tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to define a custom `LearningRateSchedule`, but AutoGraph seems to have trouble to convert it. The following code works fine without @tf.function. But it raises an error when working with `@tf.function`

```py
def linear_interpolation(l, r, alpha):
    return l + alpha * (r - l)

class TFPiecewiseSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
    # This class currently cannot be used in @tf.function, 
    # Since tf.cond See the following link for details
    def __init__(self, endpoints, end_learning_rate=None, name=None):
        """Piecewise schedule.
        endpoints: [(int, int)]
            list of pairs `(time, value)` meanining that schedule should output
            `value` when `t==time`. All the values for time must be sorted in
            an increasing order. When t is between two times, e.g. `(time_a, value_a)`
            and `(time_b, value_b)`, such that `time_a <= t < time_b` then value outputs
            `interpolation(value_a, value_b, alpha)` where alpha is a fraction of
            time passed between `time_a` and `time_b` for time `t`.
        outside_value: float
            if the value is requested outside of all the intervals sepecified in
            `endpoints` this value is returned. If None then AssertionError is
            raised when outside value is requested.
        """
        super().__init__()
        idxes = [e[0] for e in endpoints]
        assert idxes == sorted(idxes)
        self.end_learning_rate = end_learning_rate or endpoints[-1][1]
        self.endpoints = endpoints
        self.name=name

    def __call__(self, step):
        if step < self.endpoints[0][0]:
            return self.endpoints[0][1]
        else:
            for (l_t, l), (r_t, r) in zip(self.endpoints[:-1], self.endpoints[1:]):
                if l_t <= step < r_t:
                    alpha = float(step - l_t) / (r_t - l_t)
                    return linear_interpolation(l, r, alpha)

        # t does not belong to any of the pieces, so doom.
        assert self.end_learning_rate is not None
        return self.end_learning_rate

    def get_config(self):
        return dict(
            endpoints=self.endpoints,
            end_learning_rate=self.end_learning_rate,
            name=self._name,
        )

lr = TFPiecewiseSchedule([[10, 1e-3], [20, 1e-4]])
@tf.function
def f(x):
    l = layers.Dense(10)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y = l(x)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(y**2)

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, l.trainable_variables)
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, l.trainable_variables))

f(tf.random.normal((2, 3)))
```

The error message says:

> :10 f  *
>           opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, l.trainable_variables))
>
> /Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/drl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:437 apply_gradients
>           apply_state = self._prepare(var_list)
>
> /Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/drl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:614 _prepare
>           self._prepare_local(var_device, var_dtype, apply_state)
>
> /Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/drl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py:154 _prepare_local
>           super(Adam, self)._prepare_local(var_device, var_dtype, apply_state)
>
> /Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/drl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:620 _prepare_local
>           lr_t = array_ops.identity(self._decayed_lr(var_dtype))
>
> /Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/drl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:672 _decayed_lr
>           lr_t = math_ops.cast(lr_t(local_step), var_dtype)
>
> :32 **call**
>           if step < self.endpoints[0][0]:
>
> /Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/drl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:765 **bool**
>           self._disallow_bool_casting()
>
> /Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/drl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:531 _disallow_bool_casting
>           "using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`")
>
> /Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/drl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:518 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
>           " decorating it directly with @tf.function.".format(task))
>
> OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.

I think the error arises because of the if statement, so I replace the content of the `__call__` function with the following code. But almost the same error arises.

```py
        def compute_lr(step):
            for (l_t, l), (r_t, r) in zip(self.endpoints[:-1], self.endpoints[1:]):
                if l_t <= step < r_t:
                    alpha = float(step - l_t) / (r_t - l_t)
                    return linear_interpolation(l, r, alpha)

            # t does not belong to any of the pieces, so doom.
            assert self.end_learning_rate is not None
            return self.end_learning_rate
        return tf.cond(tf.less(step, self.endpoints[0][0]), lambda: self.endpoints[0][1], lambda: compute_lr(step))
```

What should I do to make the code work as I wish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is garbled by the markdown formatter, but it seems that the `__call__` function itself was not processed by AutoGraph. In the error message, converted functions are marked with an asterisk. This is a bug in the Adam optimizer. Anyway, you can annotate it directly with tf.function it will be picked up:

```
    @tf.function
    def __call__(self, step):
```

That said, there are a few things in the code that AutoGraph doesn't like: `zip`, returning from a loop, chained inequalities - it's safer to use basic constructs when possible. Sadly the errors are still you get are quite a bit confusing. Rewriting it like this should work:

```
    @tf.function
    def __call__(self, step):
        if step < self.endpoints[0][0]:
            return self.endpoints[0][1]
        else:
            # Can't return from a loop
            lr = self.end_learning_rate
            # Since it needs to break based on the value of a tensor, loop
            # needs to be a tf.while_loop
            for pair in tf.stack([self.endpoints[:-1], self.endpoints[1:]], axis=1):
                left, right = tf.unstack(pair)
                l_t, l = tf.unstack(left)
                r_t, r = tf.unstack(right)
                # Chained inequalities not supported yet
                if l_t <= step and step < r_t:
                    alpha = float(step - l_t) / (r_t - l_t)
                    lr = linear_interpolation(l, r, alpha)
                    break

        return lr
```

There is one last issue - `tf.function` doesn't like it when things create variables, so you need to move the creation of the layer and the optimizer outside:

```
lr = TFPiecewiseSchedule([[10, 1e-3], [20, 1e-4]])
l = layers.Dense(10)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr)
@tf.function
def f(x):
  ...
```

I hope this helps!